# Does solid melt on the surface when the temperature is below its freezing point?

Tags: thermodynamics

I have learnt at school that evaporation and condensation are always taking place (on the suface of a liquid) and that the vapor and liquid are in equilibrium. Does something similar happen on the surface of a solid? If not, why?
I have googled this question but I havent faound any answers.

Comment: Yes, the surface of a crystalline solid will melt slightly below the bulk melting point, sometimes called pre-melt. Since the atoms on the surface have not fully satisfied their desired crystalline bonding, they are in a higher energy state.